# JavaScript array of data sort to range

Tags: javascript

I am having array of data Ex. `var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,15]`.
If array of data number sequence match to range like more than two digits. I want to display above array of data as below.
`result = [1-5,7,8,10-12,15]`.

Can any one help me how can i achieve above result in JavaScript.

Comment: what have you tried? how would you solve this problem manually?

Comment: So, you are going from integer values in the array to string values?

Comment: Well array of numbers cannot have `-` inside it

Comment: is there any way to achieve this? out will be either array or string object.

Comment: This sentence is very difficult to understand. "If array of data number sequence match to range like more than two digits". Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if a number is in range, the change the last string or push the value to the result set.

> ```
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15
> ^                                    no predecessor, push value
> +  ^  +                              predecessor and successor, change last value
>       +  +  ^                        predecessor and previous predecessor, change last
> ```

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15],
    result = [];

array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    result.push(aa[i - 1] + 1 === a && (aa[i - 2] + 1 === aa[i - 1] || a + 1 === aa[i + 1])
        ? [result.pop().split('-')[0], a].join('-')
        : a.toString());
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for giving solution it's helped me to sort out from problem

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it

```js
function getRanges(array) {
  let ranges = [], rstart, rend;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    rstart = array[i];
    rend = rstart;
    while (array[i + 1] - array[i] == 1) {
      rend = array[i + 1];
      i++;
    }
    ranges.push(rstart == rend ? rstart+'' : rstart + '-' + rend);
  }
  return ranges;
}

const range1 = getRanges([1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,15]);
console.log(range1);
const range2 = getRanges([1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,14 ]);
console.log(range2);
const range3 = getRanges([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
console.log(range3);
```

Comment: in the first example, 7 and 8 should not be together.